How to calculate the shortest geodetic(orthodomic?) distance from a Point to LineString using GeoTools?
First of all, sorry if used wrong terms. I have a LineString on and I need to calculate the shortest distance to it from a Point using java GeoTools library.
I don't need just geometric distance, those are points on Earth (longitude and latitude) and I need to get a distance in meters.
I tried this approach, but it does not seem to give me the correct (not even close) results, and basically is just a geometrical distance.
LineString ls = ...
Point p = ...
double distance = ls.distance(p);

Among all examples I only found how to calculate distance between two points:
GeodeticCalculator gc = new GeodeticCalculator();
gc.setStartingGeographicPoint(...);
gc.setDestinationGeographicPoint(...);

double distance = gc.getOrthodromicDistance();

While it gives correct results, I don't really know how to apply the same calculation to a LineString. The calculator class does not seem to accept an arbitrary Geometry. So how can I do this to get the correct results?
Do I need to split my LineString into multiple segments, project my point onto each of them, and then use the calculator to calculate the shorted distance between all the projections and my point?

see https://stackoverflow.com/q/38404095/439194

This is based on the answer to this question, but updated to the latest versions:
import org.geotools.api.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.geotools.api.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.geotools.api.referencing.operation.TransformException;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException;
import org.locationtech.jts.operation.distance.DistanceOp;

public class ClosestPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FactoryException, TransformException {
        GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

        Coordinate[] c = new Coordinate[5];
        c[0] = new Coordinate(-49.242986, -16.662430);
        c[1] = new Coordinate(-49.241999, -16.664465);
        c[2] = new Coordinate(-49.239146, -16.663828);
        c[3] = new Coordinate(-49.239832, -16.661443);
        c[4] = new Coordinate(-49.242986, -16.662430);

        Geometry geo = gf.createPolygon(c);

        Point p = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(-49.246870, -16.665493));

        double distance = geo.distance(p);

        System.out.println("Distance: " + distance+ " in degrees");

        CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
        GeodeticCalculator gc = new GeodeticCalculator(crs);
        gc.setStartingPosition( JTS.toDirectPosition(  DistanceOp.closestPoints(geo, p)[0], crs ) );
        gc.setDestinationPosition( JTS.toDirectPosition( p.getCoordinate(), crs ) );

        distance = gc.getOrthodromicDistance();
        System.out.println("Distance: " + distance+ " in metres");
    }
}


Looks like this is exactly what I need. I saw this answer earlier but for some reason I got confused DistanceOp.closestPoints(geo, p)[0] and though it was actually DistanceOp.closestPoints(geo[0], p). So I though it's just a dumb solution that just takes the first point from geometry and calculates distance between it and the target point.
Anyway, this seems to be it. Thank you very much for your time.
